# Error the request signature. AWS ElasticSearch

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

When I want to delete an item from the index, it fails and shows us the next trace of ERROR:

> org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Cannot execute jest action , 
>   response code : 403 , error : 403 Forbidden , 
>   message : The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. 
>   Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

I have created a "removeBy..." method in the ElasticsearchRepository repository to remove items from our index:

```
public interface IndexSynonymRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<IdxSynonym, Long> {
    void removeByIdDashboardAndIdTable(Long idDashBoard, Long idTable);
}
```

The versions incorporated into my JAVA project are the following:
POM configuration versions:

```
<!-- Spring Data Jest ElasticSearch AWS -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.vanroy</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jest</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Data ElasticSearch -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Jest -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.searchbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>jest</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- ElasticSearch -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Boot -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<!-- Aws Signing Request Interceptor -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>vc.inreach.aws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-signing-request-interceptor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.20</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The roles policies that we have configured in AWS are the following:

```
Access Policy ElasticSearch:
```

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:domain/my-domain/*",
        "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:domain/my-domain"
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

```
EC2 Role Policy:
```

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "es:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:domain/my-domain",
                "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:domain/my-domain/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}`

I do not know if it is a problem of permits or if I have made an error in signing the application.

I need help to solve this problem. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi, Is your cluster configured for public access or VPC access?

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering. My cluster has it configured with access through VPC. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: In Vanroy jest configuration examples for connection with AWS ES, it's included a dependency to aws-signing-request-interceptor. Have you added that dependency?

Comment: Yes, I have it added to my project. I edit the initial question adding dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When VPC access is configured, is not necessary the aws-signing-request-interceptor when use the ES Access Policy template:

[image]

You can configure access through ES Security Group. You should add an inbound rule like this:

```
Type: HTTPS
Protocol: TCP
Port: 443
Source: sg-abcdefghijklmno (Your EC2 instance Security group)
```

Hope this helps